# Is there a best practice to avoid Django's "Found another file with the destination path" during collectstatic on production?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-jet

So I'm using Django 4.2, with Django-JET admin package via [Django-jet-reboot](https://github.com/assem-ch/django-jet-reboot) fork; it enhances Admin with nice functionality and UX.

Each time I deploy my app on production, it feels its taking much longer when it reach `collectstatic` command cause it throws `Found another file with the destination path` warnings.

Now it seems it's related to `Django-Jet`'s css & js files that needs to override `django.contrib.admin` ones, so my two questions are:

- **Is this harmless and working as designed for my use-case? or there is a better practice to handle this?**

  - (like specifically configuring not looking for those django files? or add them to local static folder?)
- **Will adding additional UI-changing package(s) be ok with this?**

  - For example I'm looking at creative tims' [Black Dashboard Django](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/black-dashboard-django) - I just manage on it's priority in INSTALLED_APPS and let it be? = after `jet` so it doesn't override that package but takes the additional ones.

#### Issue Details

```
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/base.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/changelists.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/dashboard.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/forms.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/login.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/rtl.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/css/widgets.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/SelectFilter2.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
```

And doing the `python manage.py findstatic` Command on them, gives:

```
Found 'admin/css/base.css' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jet/static/admin/css/base.css
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css
Found 'admin/css/changelists.css' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jet/static/admin/css/changelists.css
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/changelists.css
Found 'admin/css/dashboard.css' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jet/static/admin/css/dashboard.css
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/dashboard.css
Found 'admin/css/forms.css' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jet/static/admin/css/forms.css
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/forms.css
Found 'admin/css/login.css' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jet/static/admin/css/login.css
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/login.css
Found 'admin/css/rtl.css' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jet/static/admin/css/rtl.css
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/rtl.css
Found 'admin/css/widgets.css' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jet/static/admin/css/widgets.css
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/widgets.css
Found 'admin/js/SelectFilter2.js' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jet/static/admin/js/SelectFilter2.js
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/SelectFilter2.js
Found 'admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jet/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js
Found 'admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js' here:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jet/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js
  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js
```

#### My Settings

**INSTALLED APPS**

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "jet",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.forms",
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    "django_filters",
    "crispy_forms",
    "crispy_bootstrap5",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "rest_framework",
    # 'rest_framework_json_api',
    "django_extensions",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "corsheaders",
    "drf_spectacular",
]
```

**Static files Configs**

```
# STATIC
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent.parent
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR / "backend" #Main Django App Folder Name

STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR / "staticfiles")

STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    str(APPS_DIR / "static"),
]

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Got A response from Django Team:
"This is working exactly as designed. This is precisely how you replace system-supplied static files with customized versions. It’s the same concept as overriding templates."

Incase someone thought the warnings means there's more to do (Sometimes it does; if you mistakenly duplicated finders on samefiles, so check findstatic first)